# Stylus editor with highlighting and formatting for Mac

Tags: html, css, editor, stylus

Please advise if there is some lightweight text editor that can highlight and possible format [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) markup.

Now I use WebStorm and love it but it still doesn't support Stylus.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) is a very good lightweight text editor. It's highly customizable and you can find syntax highlighting/autocomplete for pretty much any language.

There's a [Stylus project](https://github.com/billymoon/Stylus/) available on github. Just download and unzip to: `~/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/` and you should be good to go.